# Redux thunk fetch returns function instead of value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch-api, redux-thunk

Hello everyone I'm a beginner currently learning programming, I'm trying to make a webapp that fetches posts from reddit and displays them in a website, I have created an async thunk to fetch the data from a reddit API, when I log it to the console the data is displayed, but whenever I try calling the fetch function and save it to a const instead of returning the object as it normally does, it returns the function.

[Picture of the array returned by 'fetchNewPosts()' in reddit.js & the fetch call  by 'getPosts() in postSlice.js'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBs4I.png)

**reddit.js** *API fetch function*

```
export const API_URL = 'https://www.reddit.com';

export const fetchNewPosts = () => async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/new.json`);
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json.data.children.map((post) => post.data))
    const posts = json.data.children.map((post) => post.data)
    return posts
}
```

**Feed.jsx**
*'fetchNewPosts()' renders an object w/ 25 posts when dispatched in Feed.jsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import {Stats} from '../components/Stats';
import { Post } from '../components/Post/Post'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import './Feed.css'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getPosts } from '../api/postsSlice';
import { fetchNewPosts } from '../api/reddit';


export const Feed = () => {
  const allInfo = useSelector(state => state.postsReducer);
  const { posts, isLoading, error } = allInfo;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getPosts());
  dispatch(fetchNewPosts())
}, [dispatch])

...
```

**postsSlice.js**

```
    import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { fetchNewPosts } from "./reddit";


export const postsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'postsSlice',
    initialState: {
        posts: [],
        isLoading: false,
        error: false,
        errorMessage: '',
        searchTerm: '',
    },
    reducers: {
        startGetPosts (state) {
            state.isLoading = true;
        },
        getPostsSuccess (state, action) {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.posts = action.payload;
        },
        getPostsFailed (state, action) {
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.error = true;
            state.errorMessage = action.payload;
        }
    }
})



export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch(startGetPosts());
        const posts = await fetchNewPosts();
        console.log(posts)
        dispatch(getPostsSuccess());
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(getPostsFailed(error.message))
    }
}


export const selectPosts = (state) => state.postsSlice.posts;

export const { 
    startGetPosts, 
    getPostsSuccess, 
    getPostsFailed 
} = postsSlice.actions;

export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

I appreciate any feedback I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing that you're missing is that **the *only* way to update state in Redux is to "dispatch" an action object that describes "what happened" and contains descriptions/data!**  Right now your code isn't doing that.

`fetchNewPosts` looks like this:

```
export const fetchNewPosts = () => async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/new.json`);
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json.data.children.map((post) => post.data))
    const posts = json.data.children.map((post) => post.data)
    return posts
}
```

*Most* of that is okay.

It's got the form of a "thunk action creator", where there's an inner function that can do some async work.  That's good.

The first three lines are fine, up through `const posts = data.children.map()`.  You made the request, got the data back, and pulled out what you needed.

However, `return posts` is wrong.  **Instead of *returning* the value, you need to *dispatch an action* containing the value**.

Fortunately, thunk functions are given the Redux `dispatch` function when they get called.  So, you can change it to this:

```
// Add dispatch as an arg to the inner function
export const fetchNewPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/new.json`);
    const json = await response.json();

    const posts = json.data.children.map((post) => post.data)
    // Dispatch an action containing the data
    // Assume that `somePostsReceivedAction` is defined elsewhere
    dispatch(somePostsReceivedAction(posts));
}
```

Note that this becomes easier if you use our official Redux Toolkit package.  It has a `createAsyncThunk` API that *does* let you just make the request and return the data, and it dispatches the actions for you:

```
const fetchNewPosts2 = createAsyncThunk(
  'posts/fetchNewPosts',
  async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/new.json`);
    const json = await response.json();
    return son.data.children.map((post) => post.data)
  }
)
```

See our Redux docs tutorials to better understand what thunks are, how to use them, and how to use Redux Toolkit:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic
- https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks